# Implement a common linked list which has a single value field

Tags: c, linux, struct, linked-list

Recently, when write some linux program in c, seems a lot place need a common linked list that could support different type of values, thus I tried to implement one, but there are still some questions.

### **Approach:**

- define a struct with pointers, then end by a value field of char[] type,
  use it as the common struct,
- define & impl method on linked list, using the common struct,
- define new struct type that has the value field of different type,
- when call the functions, just cast things as the common type,

---

### **Code:** (*draft version*)

**linked_list.h**

```
#ifndef _LINKED_LIST
#define _LINKED_LIST

// common list for any type,
struct llist_item {
    struct llist_item *next;
    char value[1];
};

// int list
struct llist_int {
    struct llist_int *next;
    int value;
};

/**
 * append item to end of list,
 * 
 * @param headp
 *  pointer to head pointer,
 * @param valuep
 *  pointer set value of deleted item into,
 * @param value_size
 *  size of value,
 * @param struct_size
 *  size of actual struct,
 * 
 * @return
 *  pointer to head,
 */
extern struct llist_item *llist_append(struct llist_item **headp, void *valuep, ssize_t value_size, ssize_t struct_size);

/**
 * delete head,
 * 
 * @param headp
 *  pointer to head pointer,
 * @param valuep
 *  pointer set value of deleted item into,
 * 
 * @return
 *  pointer to new head,
 */
extern struct llist_item *llist_del_head(struct llist_item **headp, char *valuep);

#endif
```

**linked_list.c**

```
// linked_list utility
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include "linked_list.h"

/*
   printf("error while linked_list: %s\n", strerror(errno));
   printf("linked_list succeed\n");
 */

struct llist_item *llist_append(struct llist_item **headp, void *valuep, ssize_t value_size, ssize_t struct_size) {
    struct llist_item *head = *headp;

    // create new item
    struct llist_item *new_item = (struct llist_item*) malloc(struct_size);
    new_item->next = NULL;
    memcpy(&(new_item->value), valuep, value_size);

    // append new item
    if(head == NULL) { // empty queue,
        head = new_item;
        *headp = head;
    } else {
        // find last item
        struct llist_item *tail = head;
        while(tail->next != NULL) {
            tail = tail->next;
        }   

        tail->next = new_item;
    }

    return head;
}

struct llist_item *llist_del_head(struct llist_item **headp, char *valuep) {
    struct llist_item *head = *headp;

    if(head == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        memcpy(valuep, &(head->value), sizeof(*valuep));
        *headp = head->next;
        free(head);
        return *headp;
    }
}
```

**llist_test.c**

```
// linked_list test
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include "linked_list.h"

int linked_list_test() {
    struct llist_int *int_list = NULL; // it's important to initialize this pointer as NULL explicitly,
    int i;

    for(i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        llist_append((struct llist_item **) &int_list, (void *) &i, sizeof(int), sizeof(struct llist_int));
    }

    struct llist_int *int_item;
    int value;
    if(int_list != NULL) {
        do {
            (struct llist_int *)llist_del_head((struct llist_item **) &int_list, (char *) &value);
            printf("%d\n", value);
        } while (int_list!= NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    return linked_list_test();
}
```

---

### Compile & Run

**code list**:

- *linked_list.h*, header,
- *linked_list.c*, implementation,
- *llist_test.c*, do test,

**compile - for test:**

> gcc -Wall linked_list.c  llist_test.c -o a.out

**execute:**

> ./a.out

---

**Questions:**

- The casting is complex, do there has some approach to simplify it?
- In the test method `linked_list_test()`:

  if change:

  ```
      do {
          int_item = (struct llist_int *)llist_del_head((struct llist_item **) &int_list, (char *) &value);
          printf("%d\n", value);
      } while (int_item != NULL);
  ```

  to

  ```
      do {
          (struct llist_int *)llist_del_head((struct llist_item **) &int_list, (char *) &value);
          printf("%d\n", value);
      } while (int_list!= NULL);
  ```

  Then the result is wield, instead of output:

  > 1   2   3   4   5

  it output:

  > 32513   32514   32515   32516   32517

  The difference is a pointer cast, why it makes the result different?

---

**@Update - About 2nd question**

As @BLUEPIXY described in comment, indeed it's `sizeof(*valuep)` caused the issue, now I modified the `llist_del_head()`, and provide the size in param list explicitly, and issue fixed.

The function now looks like this:

```
extern struct llist_item *llist_del_head(struct llist_item **headp, char *valuep, ssize_t value_size);
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger?

Comment: note `sizeof(*valuep)` is `1`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The code is good now, before that I did some debug via GDB to make it work. Now wish some suggestion on design & implementation, and  the 2nd question is just a wield pointer cast issue that I can't figure out in gdb.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That's important, I almost forget, will check now.

Comment: Eirc, the reason many of the casts are required is that you are using the *addresses* of objects (e.g. `&something`). When you take the address of an object with the urnary `&` operator, the result is simply *an address*. An *address* has no *type* -- it is simply a *memory location*. Therefore, to make proper use of the object address, you must *cast the address* of the object to the proper *type*.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY hey, with your tip, indeed it's `sizeof(*valuep)` cause the issue, now I modified the `llist_del_head()` to provide the size in param list explicitly, and issue fixed, thx.

Comment: @David When the address-of operator (`&`) is applied to any valid object, the result is always a typed value.  If applied to an `int`, the type is `int *`.  If applied to a `char [5]`, the result is `char (*)[5]`.  Every expression in C has a type, whether pointer or otherwise.

Comment: Tom, I agree with that, the point I was trying to make, perhaps inartfully, was that after you take the address, the result is a *bare* address that you must cast to make proper use of (if not assigning/passing as the same type). Yes the compiler will throw a type warning/error if you attempt an assignment without a proper cast to an object of a different type.

Comment: @David It should be rare to need such a cast though.  Normally if you take the address of something, and pass it to a function or assign it to a pointer, the types match and no cast is needed (that is, after all, the whole point of strict typing).  The only times casting is needed are for unusual situation where you need to do bare address arithmetic (circumventing the type system), or if you want to force something like a `const` qualifier in a situation that the compiler doesn't like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach has several problems:

- The space you set aside in the structure is only 1 byte, you cannot store types larger than 1 byte into it.
- If you were to make space for larger types there, you would still have an alignment problem: larger types may require a different alignment than is assumed by the compiler for a `char` array after a `struct llist_item *`. So even using a variable sized trailing array in the structure does not provide a viable solution.

You may use a `void *` and allocate the values separately, but this is wasteful, or use macros to implement source code templates for different types, but this is cumbersome and error prone.

C does not have the right constructions for this kind of concept, C++ does at the cost of much greater complexity.

Comment: Nice tip for the alignment part.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do, but I suggest:

1. Do not export the definition of the list in the `.h` file. The user doesn't need to know the implementation.
2. Note that your `struct llist_item` can only hold a single character. Change it to a `void *` so it can hold a pointer to any type of value.
3. having to pass the struct size in `llist_append` seems very strange as this is the size of list structure plus size of value to store. But this has to do with how you want to store "any value"

In general, the user will want you to maintain a pointer to the data the list must store. Your .h file could simply look like:

```
/* append pointer valuep to the list */
void *llist_append(void **list, void *valuep, ssize_t value_size);

/* delete the list element that contains pointer valuep */
void *llist_del_head(void **list, void *valuep);
```

and your implementation:

```
// common list for any type,
struct llist_item {
    struct llist_item *next;
    void *value;
};
```

and to append:

```
// create new item
struct llist_item *new_item = malloc(sizeof(struct llist_item));
new_item->next = NULL;
new_item->value= valuep;
```

Comment: 0)The reason writing this code is to reuse code for different type of values. 1) Good tip, might remove them if will give it to others. 2) I did consider the `void *` type for `value` field, but the base type will never be actually used, when need a new type then define a new struct, I used `char[1]` mainly because I saw a `unsigned char __pad[X];` field from `struct sockaddr_in` when write socket programs. 3) That's the only solution I know to make sure the size is correct, I saw similar approache in `inet_ntop()`.

Comment: I just tried `void * value`, seems it need to allocate memory out site of the struct itself, which is complex to maintain. Otherwise will get segment fault.

Comment: It is not more complex to maintain than your earlier solution. When deleting a node, just delete (free) the value. Alternatively, in stead of mallocing/copying the value, you can save the value (pointer) from the user so you don't need to allocate memory for it. This depends on the functionality you want to offer your user: does he want you to maintain a copy or just a pointer? In the first case, changes to the user's copy won't be reflected in the copy stored in the list, in the second case the user operates on a single copy.

Comment: Ok, it seems in c it's really difficult to write a general solution for this, different usage prefer to different solution & struct.

Comment: Eric, it isn't difficult in C. In general, the user will want you to maintain a pointer and not a copy. The user passes a pointer to something, which your list module treats as a `void *`. What the something is, is up to the user and your list module doesn't need to know anything about what it is storing. It just maintains a list. I'll update teh solution for this.

Comment: If it's just a pointer that's easy. But in some case it's simpler for user if don't need to allocate additional memory by user, e.g user want to maintain a socket fd list from client, the fd is of type `int`, user probably don't want to allocate space for the int and free it later by hand every time I guess.

Comment: Then the user passes the int and the list stores the int in the space for the `void *` because in general `sizeof(int)==sizeof(void *)` (note: the standard does not require these to be the same size but on nearly all platforms they are. So formally you must check they are the same size on your platform).